# Is the language $\{i|f(i)=1\}$ recursive, function $f$ is described further inside.

Tags: automata

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show $f$ is primitive recursive, where $f(n) = 1$ if the decimal expansion of $\pi$ contains $n$ consecutive $5$'s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183240/show-f-is-primitive-recursive-where-fn-1-if-the-decimal-expansion-of)

$$L = \{i\mid f(i)=1\}$$
$f(i)$ equals $1$ if there is a sequence of at least $i$ consecutive $5$s in the decimal expansion of $\pi$, and $0$ otherwise.

Is there a total Turing Machine that can represent that language for any $i$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'll just drop hints:

- If there's a run of $n$ fives in $\langle\pi\rangle$, the decimal expansion of $\pi$, there are also runs of $1,2,\ldots,n-1$ fives.
- We don't know the entire sequence of digits in $\langle\pi\rangle$. But there are two cases to consider: Either $\langle\pi\rangle$ has unbounded runs of fives, or it doesn't, and the maximum run has length $n$.  (we don't know precisely which is the case). Can you devise a decider (a TM that decides yes or no for every input) for each case?